Chart.js - line break at horizontal labels
With Chart.js I would like to break lines at X axis, similar to image below.
Currently, my graphic keeps rotating labels.

Current code:
const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    options: {
        scales: {
            x: {
                stacked: true,
                ticks: {
                    color: 'blue',
                    break: true,  <- Something like this
                }
            },
        },
    }
};

Edit 1: I've received this topic as possible solution (How do I place a new line in a label with Chart.js?). This does not entirely solve my issue because my labels are not static, not predefined. For clarification, labels may be todays’ employee top sellers, facilities names, and so on. Therefore, some additional undesirable coding would be needed.
Edit 2: I've decided to try that suggestion (break labels) but the result I've got was unexpected: text moved to the right.
Updated code, label creating:
let labelParts = input.Name.split(' ');
let auxLabel = labelParts.length > 1 ? [labelParts.shift(), labelParts.join(' ')] : [input.Name];
xLabels.push(auxLabel);

Updated code, graphic config:
x: {
    stacked: true,
    ticks: {
        maxRotation: 90,
        minRotation: 90,
    }
},

Sample result:


Does this answer your question? How do I place a new line in a label with Chart.js?

This does not entirely solve my issue because my labels are not static, not predefined. For clarification, labels may be todays’ employee top sellers, facilities names, and so on. Therefore, some additional undesirable coding would be needed. I've added this to the topic.

@YongShun I've added a new attempt considering that link you've mentioned. Can you please have a look?
